# searching an array using another array of values in ruby

Tags: ruby, intersection

So I have an array which shows which levels are allowed to do things.

```
allowed = ["user", "admin"]
```

There's another array that shows which groups a user belongs to.

```
groups = ["user", "crazy"]
```

What's the best way to search the allowed array for ANY of the groups a user belongs to?  I know it's easy but I'm drawing a real blank here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just `&`:

```
allowed & groups
```

Comment: Way better than my answer. +1

Comment: oh my gosh...let's all pretend this never happened ok ... ;-)  Thanks!

Comment: it has a limit on when you can approve answers...had to wait 5 minutes.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a set and do an intersection.

```
require 'set'

allowed = ["user", "admin"]
has = ["user", "print"]
puts(allowed.to_set.intersection(has.to_set)) # prints #<Set: {"user"}>
```